# Overloading Assignment Operator in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, assignment-operator

```
class Attribute
{
public:
    string data;
    Attribute *next;

    Attribute& operator = (const Attribute *attr) 
    {
        data = "dummy";
        this->next = NULL;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Attribute* atr = new Attribute("abc");
    Attribute* atr2 = new Attribute("123");

    atr2 = atr;

    atr->data = "etr";
    cout << atr2->data << endl; // Output should be "dummy" but it is "etr"

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone suggest the correct syntax or something that could make this code work?

Comment: `atr2 = atr` does not invoke `Attribute::operator=`. You are not assigning to an instance of `Attribute` - you assign to a pointer. You simply made `atr2` point to the same `Attribute` instance as `atr`. Anyway, `*atr2 = atr;` (note the star) should produce the output you expect; but I must note that your `operator=` is extremely odd (unusual signature, doesn't actually use its parameter).

Comment: `operator=` needs to take its input value by const reference instead of by pointer: `Attribute& operator=(const Attribute &attr) { data = attr.data; return *this; }` and then you need to dereference your allocated pointers when performing the assignment: `*atr2 = *atr;`